# AsyncTask- What is wrong with this type parameter?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

This is the first program I was writing to practice using an AsyncTask. I failed to resolve this error, I tried to do a few suggested fixes, but that brought errors in the previous line. So I'll be thankful if somebody can suggest me what is wrong here and how to fix it.

```
package com.example.concurrency;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class UsingAsyncTask extends Activity {
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.using_asynctask); 
        String spec="http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2F7%2F7a%2FBasketball.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fcommons.wikimedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFile%3ABasketball.png&h=340&w=340&tbnid=EJmjEDyJzrhAuM%3A&zoom=1&docid=C_hn8nOgsGmuwM&hl=en&ei=Q0o2U93LNcaIygH4mICQBQ&tbm=isch&ved=0CHwQhBwwBg&iact=rc&dur=3875&page=1&start=0&ndsp=14";
        try {URL params= new URL(spec);} catch(Exception e) {}
        Bitmap result;
        new MyTask().execute(params);// ERROR:***** params cannot be resolved to a variable*************
        imageView= new ImageView(null);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Bitmap> {

        private Bitmap loadImageFromNetwork(String url){
            try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());
            return bitmap;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params){
            //if(isCancelled()) return;
            String url=params.toString();
            final Bitmap bitmap= loadImageFromNetwork(url);
            return bitmap;
        }

        /*protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress progress){
            setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
        }*/

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what the error is.  Ah, my mistake.  It's in the code, in the form of a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
try {URL params= new URL(spec);}
```

If you create variable params like this, it exists only in scope of try-catch block. So when you're executing asyncTask it, is not recognized. Do something like this:

```
   URL params;
   try {
     params = new URL(spec);
   }
```

Also as You wrote your code like above, asyncTask expects String as the first parameter (First parameter of asyncTask is what is what You receive as doInBackground parameter). Change doInBackground to:

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... params)
```

And then, get Your parameter by calling params[0] (because statement "URL..." means array of URLs with unknown size).

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer. I don't have enough points to upvote your answer but I won't forget to do it as soon as I get a reputation of 15 points.

Comment: @Zarah you can still accept as the correct answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. This will reward the user and show others that this answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

`params` shows not defined because you declare it inside of a `try` apart from where you try to use it. This puts it out of scope because if there is an exception then the variable won't be initialized.

Change it to something like

```
try {
    // here they can live peacefully together within the same scope
    URL params= new URL(spec);
    Bitmap result;
    new MyTask().execute(params);   
} catch(Exception e) {}
```

Also, you really should do *something* if you catch an exception. Leaving it blank like that won't do you any good and may very well lead to problems.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure do declare params outside of the try-catch block to dodge the "params cannot be resolved to a variable" error.

You also have two `doInBackground()` methods in your AsyncTask. I imagine you would want to delete the second but change the type of the first to URL, or it will still fail.

```
package com.example.concurrency;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class UsingAsyncTask extends Activity {
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.using_asynctask); 
        String spec="http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2F7%2F7a%2FBasketball.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fcommons.wikimedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFile%3ABasketball.png&h=340&w=340&tbnid=EJmjEDyJzrhAuM%3A&zoom=1&docid=C_hn8nOgsGmuwM&hl=en&ei=Q0o2U93LNcaIygH4mICQBQ&tbm=isch&ved=0CHwQhBwwBg&iact=rc&dur=3875&page=1&start=0&ndsp=14";
        URL params;
        try {
            params = new URL(spec);
        } catch(Exception e) {}
        Bitmap result;
        new MyTask().execute(params);// ERROR:***** params cannot be resolved to a variable*************
        imageView= new ImageView(null);
    }
    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Bitmap> {

        private Bitmap loadImageFromNetwork(String url){
            try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());
            return bitmap;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... params){
            //if(isCancelled()) return;
            String url=params.toString();
            final Bitmap bitmap= loadImageFromNetwork(url);
            return bitmap;
        }

        /*protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress progress){
            setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
        }*/

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had mistakenly enabled an auto-generation of the second of the second doInBackground method, and overlooked it. I have now removed it. Thank you very much.